# How to Remove Hover State on Mobile with Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, touch-event

**Question, Answer Below**

I know this sounds like a common question, and I did a lot of searching, but I couldn't find an answer to my problem. Let's suppose I have this code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <style>
            nav{ background:yellow; }
            nav ul:before{content:"Menu";}
            nav ul>li{display:none;}
            nav ul:hover>li{display:block;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test Page</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="/search">Search</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <main>Content here!</main>
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("nav").on("click","a",function(e){
                var link = this;
                $.ajax({
                    url: link.href,
                    dataType:"html",
                    success:function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                        $("main").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                        console.log(textStatus);
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works great on mobile, but if the mobile site is using ajax to load the content the menu will stay open until the user clicks away. What I want though, is for the the menu to collapse when they click on an link.

Using a separate class to manage the hover effect and then applying it through javascript doesn't work, because as soon as the new content is loaded I need to reapply the possibility of hovering over the nav, which will just cause the nav to open back up if the user hasn't clicked away from the original menu hover.

Any ideas? So far my best solution is to manage the hover in js and add a fallback option of css, so users on mobile devices without js (really it cant be many) will have to click away to close the nav.

**UPDATE... Not working**

I believe I have come up with a solution that works. It's not perfect, but it does what I want. I added this to document on ready

```
$('nav').on("touchstart","ul",function(){
    $('li',this).css('display', 'block');
}).on("mouseenter","ul",function(){
    $('li',this).css('display', 'block');
}).on("mouseleave","ul",function(){
    $('li',this).css('display', 'none');
})
```

and then this to the on click event

```
$('nav ul:hover>li').css('display', 'none');
```

**FINAL UPDATE, WORKING**

My previous update was not actually working as I had thought. It had an issue when going from portrait to landscape and also on full desktop. So, after some more work I found another way which works even better. The website I am building uses headjs and with that I can apply styles specifically to mobile devices.

So completely disregarding my previous update, adding this code to the loadpage function

```
$('.mobile nav ul').addClass('collapse');
```

This code to the on click function

```
$('.mobile nav').on("touchstart","ul",function(){
    $(this).removeClass("collapse");
})
```

And this class to the stylesheet

```
.mobile nav ul.collapse>li{display:none;}
```

I was able to overcome the issue.

Comment: Can't understand your problem. Could you add working code snippet?

Comment: Sure, I will update my post with a full example, however I believe I solved my issue moments after posting this question... even though I had previously spent like 4 hours trying to solve it... lol such is life.

Comment: I still don't understand. What should see users without js when click on link?

Comment: It's okay, I have figured it out. My update above didn't actually fix the issue entirely, it had problems on full desktop and also when the user switched from the menu being collapsed to being not collapsed, ie rotating their phone to landscape.

Comment: I'll post another update after this that gives the final working solution, but to be clear my problem was collapsing the drop expanded menu on mobile devices after loading content from an ajax request. If you tested the example above on a mobile device you would see that when you load a page into the content area through ajax, the nav remained expanded. With regular page loading this isn't an issue wince the reloading of the page will clear out the expanded menu. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: Create working snippet (with issues) on http://jsfiddle.net please.